# Can't attach remote debugger to w3wp.exe when there is a breakpoint. -> The remote connection has been lost

Tags: asp.net, debugging, iis-7.5, w3wp

I am trying to debug a ASP.NET application which runs on a IIS 7.5 in the local network (Windows 7 Ultimate). I am deploying via Web Publish (Debug). I installed the remote debugging tool for Visual Studio 2015 on the remote machine.

When I want to attach the remote debugger to the `w3wp.exe` process and have **no** breakpoint active, it looks like everything works since I also can see the connection in the Remote Debugger on the remote machine. But as soon I want to set a breakpoint I get:

> a remote operation takes longer than expected

which will change to a

> The network connection to MACHINENAME:4020 has been lost. Debugging will be aborted.

after a while. This happens also when I start attaching the debugger when there are already active breakpoints.

What I tried so far:

- Set **Ping enabled** to false in IIS for this Application Pool
- Enabled **Emit debug Information** in the Web Deploy Settings
- Disabled all Firewalls for the remote and develop machine